# Hadoop in a RESTful Java Web Application - Conflicting URI templates

Tags: java, rest, hadoop, web, hdfs

I have a small Java Web Application in which I am using Jersey 1.12 and the Hadoop 1.0.0 JAR file (hadoop-core-1.0.0.jar).  When I deploy my application to my JBoss 5.0 server, the log file records the following error:

```
SEVERE: Conflicting URI templates. The URI template / for root resource class   
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.web.resources.NamenodeWebHdfsMethods and the URI  
template / transform to the same regular expression (/.*)?
```

To make sure my code is not the problem, I have created a fresh web application that contains nothing but the Jersey and Hadoop JAR files along with a small stub. My web.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-  class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mytest/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>    
   <session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
   </session-config>
   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

My simple RESTful stub is as follows:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/mytest")
public class MyRest {

@Context
private UriInfo context;

  public MyRest() {
  }
}
```

In my regular application, when I remove the Hadoop JAR files (and the code that is using Hadoop), everything works as I would expect.  The deployment is successful and the remaining RESTful services work. I have also tried the Hadoop 1.0.1 JAR files and have had the same problems with the conflicting URL template in the NamenodeWebHdfsMethods class. Any suggestions or tips in solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I've fixed the problem by adding init-params to instruct the Jersey ServletContainer to only search for resources I've defined in a particular package (see below).

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param> 
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass</param-name> 
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig</param-value> 
    </init-param> 
    <init-param> 
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name> 
        <param-value>org.test.myrest</param-value> 
    </init-param> 
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: I have a similar problem but this hasn't solved mine. Anyone can suggest another solution?

Comment: found out the hard way. went to dig into the source code.
We could create the server like this, explictly specifying the config class that we want:
HttpServer server = HttpServerFactory.create(WSProperties.ADDRESS, new PackagesResourceConfig("my.packages"));

As for why there is a problem in specifying it in web.xml, it still remains a mystery to me..

Answer (score 0):

I have got the similar problem. The issue was produced because i had changed the package of REST classes. When the GlassFish server is starting it says that has found previous classes. In the log of GlassFish v3 you can find the line "INFO: Root resource classes found:", and probably you will see duplications.

Now, i am seeking to clean the resource classes.